# Error al crear grupo relacionado Muchos a muchos con Vehiculos Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando crear un Grupo, el cual se encuentra relacionado Muchos a muchos con Vehiculos.
Al momento de guardar un grupo con 2 vehiculos, me retorna un error 500 desde el navegador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago la prueba en postman, le paso el endpoint, y la data ( un grupo y dos vehiculos asociados).

```
{
    "name": "groupName",
    "vehicles": [
        211,
        177
    ]
}
```

Me devuelve 201, creando el grupo con name en null, y le pasa todos los vehiculos (yo solo le envío 2).

```
{
    "group": {
        "id": 87,
        "company_id": 27,
        "name": null,
        "created_at": "2022-01-24 11:07:16",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-24 11:07:16",
        "is_active": true,
        "vehicles": [
            {
                "id": 154,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 2,
                "plate": "AA-sb-38",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 155,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 1,
                "plate": "AA-BB-CC",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 175,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 4,
                "plate": "Bici-KK9-2",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 176,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 3,
                "plate": "CCCC99",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 177,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 1,
                "plate": "CGAM-1428",
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 211,
                "company_id": 27,
                "tipo_vehicle_id": 4,
                "plate": "AA77AA5",
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### Código

#### group

así están relacionados mis modelos

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "group"

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :vehicles, join_table: "group_vehicle"
...
```

#### vehicle

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "vehicle"

  has_many :routes
  has_many :user_mobiles

  belongs_to :tipo_vehicle
  belongs_to :company
...
```

#### group_vehicle

```
class GroupVehicle < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "group_vehicle"
    #belongs_to :vehicleTable
    belongs_to :group
```

#### group_controller (metodo create)

```
POST /api/v2/groups
  def create
    # abort group_params.inspect
    @group = @current_company.groups.new(group_params)
    @group.is_active = true
    # abort group_params.inspect
    if @group.save
      vehicles = @current_company.vehicles.where(is_active: 1)
      abort vehicles.inspect
      @group.vehicles << vehicles

      unless params[:vehicles].blank?
        params[:vehicles].each do |vehicle|
          group_vehicle = GroupVehicle.new
          group_vehicle.group_id = @group.id
          group_vehicle.vehicle_id = vehicle[:id]
          group_vehicle.save
        end
      end

      successful_response(@group, Api::V2::GroupSerializer, :created)
    else
      errors_response(@group.errors)
    end

  end
```

Alguna idea de que puede estar ocuriendo?
Les agradezco de antemano

Comment: ...pero y cual es el error 500? eso es clave para saber cual es el problema.

Comment: Cuando usas `has_and_belongs_to_many` no es necesario crear un modelo para la tabla intermedia (pero no es problema). Estás haciendo `@group.vehicles << @current_company.vehicles.where(is_active: 1)` lo cual está asignando todos los vehículos activos al grupo que estás creando. Con respecto al error 500, mira en el log cómo estás enviando los parámetros y compara como se están enviando desde postman